# I can't get the UI Text View Keybord to disappear

Tags: xcode

Hi this is my code i am trying to get the UI text view keyboard to disappear. I have 2 text fields the second one is text view. I try and drag the action but it wont let me. Please help!!!!!

```
- (IBAction)dismiss1:(id)sender{

[sender resignFirstResponder];
}

- (IBAction)dismiss2:(id)sender2{

[field2 resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UITextView doesn't have event actions.

```
Import <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> in header file and use below code to disapear keyboard when click on return button.

- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{

    if ([text isEqualToString:@"\n"]) {

        [self.textView resignFirstResponder];
        // Return FALSE so that the final '\n' character doesn't get added
        return NO;
    }
    // For any other character return TRUE so that the text gets added to the view
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Hey sorry i am a new developer so do i put the first part in the .h file and then repeat everything else in the .m file? and i have field2 so would i replace textView with that? Thanks!

Comment: @JoeMasciantonio, yes. Like this: interface yourheaderfilename : baseclass<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>

Comment: Im sorry i am still having trouble

Comment: - (BOOL)field2:(UITextView *)field2 shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    
    if ([text isEqualToString:@"\n"]) {
        
        [self->field2 resignFirstResponder];
        // Return FALSE so that the final '\n' character doesn't get added
        return NO;
    }
    // For any other character return TRUE so that the text gets added to the view
    return YES;
}

Comment: i think i get it now do i make a class for it then put the class as th class for the text view?

Comment: @JoeMasciantonio, paste your total .h and .m file, I will try to update and paste back

Comment: I got it! Thank you ver much